# Traverse up until find attribute id

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I have to traverse up until element have id attribute. My problem here is element is not definite and sometimes parent have id attribute, sometimes grandparent have id attribute like that goes on. I try like

```
var id = $(this).closest().find("['id']").attr("id");
```

i dont have such ideas to do this . Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `[id]` selector string *inside* the `.closest`, so that `closest` returns the element with an ID. Note that the selector string shouldn't have `"`s around the `id`:

```js
$('span').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).closest("[id]").attr("id");
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">outer
  <div>inner
    <span>click here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```